# How to fuzz shared objects?

Tags: linux, exploit-development

I know there have been similar questions about that topic, but I think mine differs from the others. I have this application which I am able to crash, but the error seems to happen inside of a shared object library, which gets loaded by the application. So my question is, how do I proceed further?  I attached the application to GDB and let the application crash. But how could I find out if the error relies in the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. For example, if you call a `printf()` with a `NULL` as format string, you will get a segfault in the libc, although it won't be a libc error.

But you can be nearly sure, that the shared library doesn't checks some of the data structures it gets from the main program (or from another dlls). C libraries doesn't need to do that (normally).

And if something isn't checked against NULL-pointer dereference, probably it wasn't checked also against buffer overrun. And such errors are mostly caused be NULL-dereference. You should always check on the asm-level (even with the gdb), what caused the crash, and to make an assumption, what were it on the C level.